# Java: Exit button. [Much explanation required]

Tags: java, button, exit

How do I make a button, that would exit java application? This has to be a button in-game. I should be able to manage his location. You see - I am brand new to java, and only explored it by watching tutorial series on how to make a RPG style game. So all that stuff with "How to change the buttons location, style, size etc." would be highly appreciated.

Comment: You really need to provide some more context. What kind of game? Show some code. It really depends on how the entire program works.

Comment: Add a button with an action handler method calling `System.exit(0);`

Comment: Please work on your search skills.

Comment: Arc676 well.. it has alot of code... It's a game afterall...

Answer (score 1):

Create your button & attach a listener to it that would call

```
System.exit(0);
```

on click. It shall shut down the **JVM** & your app.

**EDIT:**

```
JButton yourButton = new JButton("Exit");

yourButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        JButton clickedBtn = (JButton) e.getSource();

        if(clickedBtn == yourButton)
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }
});

// Or using Java8

yourButton.addActionListener(e -> {
    if(yourButton == (JButton) e.getSource())
        System.exit(0);
    }
});
```

Comment: More info please. What commands do I need, what is the best way to insert this in code etc.

Comment: Thanks. Do I need a separate class for that? How do I change where does the button go? And can I give it textures? If yes, then how?

Comment: you have nothing to change here. Just apply this on the button of your choice. (It would be placed in a `JPanel` or a `JFrame`)

Comment: Uhm.. how do I do that? Sorry for being so dumb at Java...

Comment: Check this link : http://www.java2s.com/Code/JavaAPI/javax.swing/JButtonaddActionListenerActionListeneract.htm

Comment: Ok.. That didn't explain how can I change the position, texture and etc. of the button. Also - I need it in-game, which means no other tabs... So that wasn't really helpfull, sorry. But thanks for what You gave :)